# Comparing a specific string in two csv files and making third csv based on those strings

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I have this csv file:

```
OU                                   Mailfile   
CORP:Jenny Smith:                    mail/246802.nsf
"CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:"       mail/123456.nsf
STORE:Mary Poppins:                  mail/789012.nsf
STORE:Tony Stark:                    mail/345678.nsf
STORE:Carmen Sandiego:               mail/901234.nsf
NEWS:Peter Parker:                   mail/567890.nsf
NEWS:Clark Kent:                     mail/654321.nsf
STORES:store123                      mail/369121.nsf
NEWS:CORPmanager                     mail/137112.nsf
NEWS:STOREmanager                    mail/083561.nsf
```

Then file2.csv:

```
OU                      
CORP
STORE     
NEWS
```

For every line in file2.csv that has 'CORP', 'STORE', or 'NEWS', I want to search through file1.csv and create a file, such as STOREall.csv, CORPall.csv, and NEWSall.csv.

Such as NEWSall.csv

```
OU                                   Mailfile

NEWS:Peter Parker:                   mail/567890.nsf
NEWS:Clark Kent:                     mail/654321.nsf
NEWS:CORPmanager                     mail/137112.nsf
NEWS:STOREmanager                    mail/083561.nsf
```

But I'm getting this output instead:

In CORPall.csv

```
OU                                   Mailfile
CORP:Jenny Smith:                    mail/246802.nsf
CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:         mail/123456.nsf
NEWS:CORPmanager                     mail/137112.nsf
```

Then NEWSall.csv

```
OU                                   Mailfile
NEWS:Peter Parker:                   mail/567890.nsf
NEWS:Clark Kent:                     mail/654321.nsf
```

Since CORP is also in news, it appears in the CORPall.csv. I don't want that. If it says `NEWS` before the `:` then that should be in NEWSall.csv, etc.

I used this snippet that someone showed me on here:

```
for dept in OUList['OU']:
    df[df['OU'].str.contains(dept)]
    df_dept['OU'].to_csv(f'{dept}all.csv', index=False)
```

It works great. But it only looks for what's in the whole file. So I need a way to search before the `:` (mind there's two in some cases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) to filter the dataframe by checking if the start of each string element matches the pattern in the `OUList`.

```py
for dept in OUList['OU']:
    df_dept = df[df['OU'].str.startswith(f'{dept}:')]
    df_dept.to_csv(f'{dept}all.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like the "OU" column should be split into two columns on the `:` character.  You can do this with `df['OU'].str.split(':')`.  Save the output to new columns and then you can use the same filter technique on the column created from the left of `:`